# Shell Script Make a copy of newest file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a directory on my linux computer (centOS) which is continuously updated with new files.

Some of these files are TXT files, and some are WAV files. I am interested in the WAV file.

> Directory of File recordings:
>    [image] 20150721191815.WAV   2015-07-21 19:18    31K
>    [image] 20150721210456.WAV   2015-07-21 21:05    14K
>     [image]20150722115532.WAV   2015-07-22 11:55    16K
>     [image]20150722115724.WAV   2015-07-22 11:57    8.3K
>   [image]20151012.txt 2015-10-12 22:41    174K

•I wish to write a shell script, where it grabs the most recent wav file, and copies it to a new file. This new file will be over-written every time the shell script is executed. The wav files have a time stamp as the file name as shown in the example.

•The script must not mistaken the TXT files

Is this doable in shell? I'm pretty beginner at this stuff. I am running CentOS linux.

Comment: It's doable, your question would be better if you give it a try and ask about a specific problem you run into.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

```
#!/bin/bash

# List all the *.wav files, in descending order of timestamp (newest first)
# Get the first one in the list (that is the newest)
NEWEST=`ls -at *.wav | head -1`

# Copy the newest file to 'newest.wav'
cp "$NEWEST" newest.wav
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I do admit to not much effort on trying to figure it out. Sorry Pedro Lobito